# Opening Firebase deeplink from QR code just opens in the app without reading the URL

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links to deeplink to users profiles. I set up a QR code with the users profile URL which the app correctly reads and routes to the appropriate view when tapped on from safari, notes, and imessage. But, when I scan the URL from a QR code, it only opens in the app and doesn't read any incoming URL. I'm using SwiftUI and here is the code I use to open URLs

```
 .onOpenURL { incomingURL in
        print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
        DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { dynamicLink, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                 print("Error here: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                 return
            }
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                 RoutingService.instance.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
}
```

To generate the QR code, I'm using

```
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins


class QRCodeGenerator {
    
    static let instance = QRCodeGenerator()
    
    let context = CIContext()
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    
    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage {
        filter.message = Data(string.utf8)

        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
            if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            }
        }

        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle") ?? UIImage()
    }
    
}
```

[image: screenshot of scanning QR code in ios camera app]

As the options are shown in the image attached, when I open in safari, it opens into safari in the preview page, then I tap open and it gets read fine. But when I tap open in BeBigger, it only recognized that it should be opened in my app. I think this is an issue with Firebase Deeplinks, anyone have a workaround, maybe a way to force the URL into safari first? Heres a sample URL generated with deeplinks: `https://bebigger.page.link/tiRtza413UDMKcyN8` which decodes to `https://bebigger.app/?location=incoming_friend_requests&id=NTDLrYfUWlhFVNQA1zwcg6qLNNg2`. Thanks

Comment: You found solution about this problem, the same things (

Comment: @AndrewSas sadly i never did